# Why does PortAudio record sound with spaces inside?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, portaudio

I got problem running this code [PortAudio example](http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html) on my Raspberry Pi in Qt Creator 5. My device is USB PnP microphone. 
`.asoundrc`is configured:

```
    pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:2,0"
  }
}
```

After compilation in terminal I got:

```
patest_record.c
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_asym.c:106:(_snd_pcm_asym_open) playback slave is not defined
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

=== Now recording!! Please speak into the microphone. ===
index = 32768
index = 68608
index = 106496
index = 141312
index = 174080
index = 215040
index = 220500
sample average = -nan
Wrote data to 'recorded.raw'
Error: No default output device.
```

The file I recorded seems to have correct samples because mostly I can hear sound that was played to mic but it seems to be broken or not continously recording - Audacity I have [Wave shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KHeg.png)

In addition I can say that `arecord` command record everything perfect, but I need to do some processing after record in C++. Does anyone know how to solve the issue? Maybe I can replace PA with any other lib?